# How can I run Ubuntu inside Windows 7?

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, virtualization

I have Windows 7. I want to run Ubuntu inside it and don't want to loose any data.. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide any more details on your exact needs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Vmware workstation (commercial) or VirtualBox (free)

Comment: Can you give me some more information??

Comment: +1 for virtualbox. Its free and in my experience works better under ubuntu than Wmware. Also virtualbox is used by the TestDrive project for used for testing latest Ubuntu development snapshots so its support under Ubuntu is better than Vmware.

Comment: Virtualbox? Sure about the fact that Ubuntu can run fine with 128(256 is the max) MB of graphical memory in total?

Answer (score 5):

Besides VMWare and Virtualbox, there is the [Ubuntu Wubi installer](http://wubi-installer.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and install [Vmplayer](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and also download an ubuntu ISO . You then need to build a new virtual machine while providing it the ubuntu ISO . After installation allow VMplayer to install VMTools to enable feature like copy paste and drag and drop across the virtual machine and the host.

Answer (score 1):

If you get VMware (Player or Workstation), you can get a pre built Ubuntu machine and you won't have to go through the hassle of installing it your self (even though its pretty easy)

[VMware Virtual Appliance Marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/508)

Also, the Linux Machines should be free of charge (I don't see any paid ones)

Answer (score 1):

Just downloaded Ubuntu 10.04 a week ago using the Wubi windows installer. It was about 1 hour download, and Wubi effortlessly installed it leaving everything in tact. When you reboot you have choice to dual boot into your current system or choose Ubuntu and hit enter. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox
for running linux inside windows 7 or any Microsoft based operating system

Comment: You shouldn't just paste links. Good answer includes contents of that link (not copy-pasted, but most important things).