# how do i install ubuntu 12.04 inside windows 7

Tags: system-installation

installing ubuntu inside windows 7 is not an option available for my system i guess.
i dont have a previous version installed on my machine as it was giving me problems regarding the grub with dual boot. is it because my machine is 64-bit ? any solution so that i dont have to restructure my hdd or format the whole laptop altogether? ram is 3gb only so i cant run it on vmware etc too gives a hard time that way. i only need it for shell scripting and c/c++/java coding

Comment: Could be similar http://askubuntu.com/questions/583/how-can-i-run-ubuntu-inside-windows-7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install 12.04 by using WUBI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-by-using-wubi)

Answer (score 1):

Can't run it in VmWare? Try VirtualBox. If you only want it for shell scripting and coding, do you need a particular desktop environment? If not, I'd recommend Lubuntu, as LXDE is much lighter than Gnome (whether Unity, Gnome Shell or Gnome Classic) or KDE. Apparently some people got Ubuntu working in Microsoft VirtualPC (not supported, but can work).

Comment: I can recommend Lubuntu inside VirtualBox - works beautifully.